# How can I get started with Quickblox API and Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

I am trying to develop a very simple chat application using quickblox and swift.

Knowing that there are few tutorials online that try to explain the process, I started with creating a user in the application dashboard and getting its credentials to initiate the connection. (I am certain that the user credential are correct and the dashboard is correctly set as I have followed this [tutorial](https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Guide:_Getting_Started_with_Chat_API))

Here is the Application view controller:

```
        import UIKit
        import Quickblox

        class ViewController: UIViewController {



            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()


                let user = QBUUser()
                user.id = 29777469
                user.password = "tahrisqalli"




                QBChat.instance().connect(with: user) { (error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error: \(error)")
                    }
                    else {
                        print("login to chat succeeded")

                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

and following is the error I get telling me that I did not connect successfully.

```
2017-07-11 11:33:50.837 QuickbloxTutorial[1045:24701] [ChatService] Connecting to Chat, host: chat.quickblox.com, user JID: 29777469-0@chat.quickblox.com/DCB0A1F4-3A56-49AD-9639-8C2A6BBE7B08
    2017-07-11 11:33:52.042 QuickbloxTutorial[1045:24711] [ChatService] Stream isSecure: YES
    2017-07-11 11:33:52.658 QuickbloxTutorial[1045:24722] [ChatService] Stream did connect, supportsStartTLS: YES
    2017-07-11 11:33:52.824 QuickbloxTutorial[1045:24722] [ChatService] Did not authenticate, error: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
    error: Optional(Error Domain=com.quickblox.chat Code=401 "<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>})
    2017-07-11 11:33:52.842 QuickbloxTutorial[1045:24722] [ChatService] Did disconnect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to log in with a user.

After this, You can connect with chat and it is best for you to use `ServicesManager` class that manage session automatically.

```
let loginUser = QBUUser()
loginUser.id = 29777469
loginUser.password = "tahrisqalli"

ServicesManager.instance().authService.logInWithUser(loginUser, completion: { (response, qbUser) in
if qbUser != nil {
     ServicesManager.instance().chatService.connectWithCompletionBlock { (error) in
          if error != nil {
             print("user not connected error: ",error?.description)
          } else {
             //user connect successfully
          }
     }
     print(qbUser)
} else {
     print(response.error?.description)
  }
})
```

Comment: Can I know the difference between the user I have created, qbUser, and loginUser, and how can I get the credentials of each one of them?

Comment: In the line where I have '})' I get some kind of syntax error telling me "expected expression"

Comment: I get 'use of unresolved Identifier ServicesManager', should I import something?

Comment: You can get file from: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat-swift/sample-chat-swift/Classes/Services

Comment: Now I get: type ServicesManager has no member instance

Comment: Basically, you have to make an instance of this class that is sharedInstance.

Comment: The ServicesManager.swift class also seems to have so many errors, maybe because it is a Swift 2 version, and I am writing my app in Swift 3?

Comment: Yes may be, you can download the lettest example and use the ServicesManager.swift https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat-swift